# Append top level menu href to bottom of subchild

Tags: jquery

I have a menu with top-level links which have associated sub-menu links.

How can I append individual top-level links (i.e. the href) to the bottom of their associated sub-menu? (I've already set preventedDefault on this top menu link in another part of the function.)

In the below fiddle I'm attempting to use .each(index) to output the correct top-level href to the bottom of the associated sub-menu list but all top-level items are output in each case. I've attempted a number of other approaches but nothing works as expected.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cm2uo1pg/)

```html
<ul class="main">
  <li><a href="http://google1.com">Top link 1</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li><a href="http://google.com">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://google.com">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://google.com">Three</a></li>
       <!-- TTop Link 1 href should be appended here-->
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://google2.com">Top link 2</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li><a href="http://google.com">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://google.com">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://google.com">Three</a></li>
       <!-- Top Link 2 href should be appended here -->
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://google3.com">Top link 3</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li><a href="http://google.com">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://google.com">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://google.com">Three</a></li>
      <!-- Top Link 3 href should be appended here-->
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
var topLevelLink = $('.main > li > a');

topLevelLink.each(function(index) {
    var topLevelLinkHref = $(this).attr('href', index);
  console.log(topLevelLinkHref);
   // create a new link at the bottom of the list and set the href to be our original top level link
   $('.inner').append('<li class="js-menu-item"><a href="' + topLevelLinkHref + '">See all</a></li>');
});


/* for (var i = 0; i < topLevelLink; i++) {
  var topLevelLinkHref = topLevelLink[i].attr('href');
  console.log(topLevelLinkHref)
  $('.inner').append('<li class="js-menu-item"><a href="' + topLevelLinkHref + '">See all</a></li>');
} */
```

Comment: I can not understand what you want to try. You want to append Top level href in submenus? ex: `<a href="http://google3.com">Top link 3</a>` this one you want to append in submenu href 
?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use [:eq() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/#index) which is used to select the element by index. You've to loop through all divs and get `href` of top level menu and then check the `index` of the item within the loop with `count` and at last check `.inner:eq(" + count + ")` and append your top level menu as a submenu in `.inner` div.

```js
var count = 0;    
var topLevelLink = $('.main > li > a');

$.each(topLevelLink, function (index, item) {
    var topLevelLinkHref = $(this).attr('href');
    
    if (index === count) { 
        $(".inner:eq(" + count + ")").append('<li class="js-menu-item"><a href="' + topLevelLinkHref + '">See all</a></li>'); // append top level href in submenu
    }
    
    count++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="main">
  <li><a href="http://google1.com">Top link 1</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li><a href="http://google.com">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://google.com">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://google.com">Three</a></li>
       <!-- TTop Link 1 href should be appended here-->
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://google2.com">Top link 2</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li><a href="http://google.com">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://google.com">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://google.com">Three</a></li>
       <!-- Top Link 2 href should be appended here -->
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://google3.com">Top link 3</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li><a href="http://google.com">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://google.com">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://google.com">Three</a></li>
      <!-- Top Link 3 href should be appended here-->
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```